# configuration file routine:STR_COPY:variable has no value

Tags: openssl

As I can't get out which file this is being generated from, I have no idea how to grab the variable that isn't set.
But the error resembles an old issue where a variable wasn't correctly set in the default config or sourced variables file.

I do have a default config under `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and it's the default packaged with the openssl package.

Here's the full output:

```
[Torxed@Daylight ipsec.d]$ sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private/testKey.pem --in certs/testCert.pem -name "My own VPN client certificate" -certfile cacerts/rootCert.pem -caname "StrongSwan Root CA" -out test.p12

140093433759384:error:0E065068:configuration file routines:STR_COPY:variable has no value:conf_def.c:584:line 167
```

Normally SSL will throw you the file that generates the error, so I'm kinda lost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple really.

`/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` had a minor configuration issue.
Apparently openssl had updated requiring additional fields but since the package manager respects personal configurations it had stored another config file as `.backup` along side of the configuration used.

Replaced my config with a newer default, and works.

Comment: Which "minor configuration issue"?

Comment: @Matthieu not to sure. Again, there was a new mandatory field in `openssl.conf` and the old configuration file didn't have it. The `openssl.conf.pacnew` contained it (as my package manager pacman honors user changes before system upgrade changes.). Basically I had deferred from the default configuration, so if you're getting this error - I'd suggest starting off with a default configuration and work towards your changes. You'll quickly discover what fields you need and what you can modify/take away.

Comment: One year later I won't be mad ;) OpenVPN has the same problem when you try generating the CA certificate, because `export KEY_ALTNAMES="somename"` is missing from `easy-rsa/vars` (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/serverguide/+bug/1504676). I thought it could be something equivalent here...

Comment: @Matthieu Glad you understand haha, I actually tried to grab my old configuration from a server I knew I hadn't deleted many files from. But I've modified them enough that it wouldn't be a reliable source of information after all. Yea OpenVPN changed it's easy-rsa structure a bit. And it differs from OpenSSL standard. I think the latest branch I've got has fixed it, but the link is a good source of information. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem which currently persists in Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.10.

What has happened is that OpenSSL has changed the certificate requirements, but several guides fail out of the box.

The solution is to add the following:

```
export KEY_ALTNAMES="something"
```

anywhere the in vars file.

There was already a bug report filed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/serverguide/+bug/1504676). And a relevant Ubuntu thread [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218935)